# Trace of positive definite matrix trick

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I’m reading a paper and came across the following simplification

$$ \text{tr}(A^TBA) = \sum_{i}a_i^TBa_i $$

For a positive definite matrix $AA^T$ and orthonormal matrix $B$. Would anyone kindly show how this is the case?

Comment: This is very basic matrix algebra. The trace of $A^TBA$ is the sum of its diagonal elements. The $i$-th diagonal element of $A^TBA$ is $a_i^TBa_i$ (here $a_i$ refers to the $i$-th column of $A$). Hence the result.

Comment: there are some oddities about **"positive definite matrix $AA^T$   and orthonormal matrix $B.$"**  You should give a link to the article and say what page

Comment: Right below equation (11) on the second page

https://www.ece.queensu.ca/people/S-D-Blostein/papers/PAMI-3DLS-1987.pdf

Admittedly, my linear algebra hasn’t been used in quite some time so I lack any intuition to see the result @user1551 has mentioned. Still trying to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{split}\text{tr}(A^TBA)&=\text{tr}(\begin{pmatrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{pmatrix}^T B\begin{pmatrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{pmatrix})\\
&=\text{tr}(\begin{pmatrix}a_1^T\\
\vdots\\a_n^T\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_1&...&b_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{pmatrix})\\
&=\text{tr}\begin{pmatrix}a_1^Tb_1&...&a_1^Tb_n\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_n^Tb_1&...&a_n^Tb_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\begin{pmatrix}(a_1^Tb_1...a_1^Tb_n)a_1&...&(a_1^Tb_1...a_1^Tb_n)a_n\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\(a_n^Tb_1...a_n^Tb_n)a_1&...&(a_n^Tb_1...a_n^Tb_n)a_n\end{pmatrix}\right)\\
&=\sum a_i^TBa_i\end{split}$$

Comment: Awesome, that clarifies things. I guess you could then say
$$
\begin{split}
B\begin{pmatrix}a_1&...&a_n\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}Ba_1&...&Ba_n\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{split}
$$

which is what I was having troubling visualizing.